# End tag for an element having attribute in xml

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, soa, bpel

I have a xsd like this :

....

```
<xsd:element name="Summary">

      <xsd:complexType>

        <xsd:attribute name="Count" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>

      </xsd:complexType>

    </xsd:element>
```

It is generating the xml like this :

....

```
 <Summary Count="3"/>
```

But I need the xml to be generated like this :

```
  <Summary Count="3"></Summary>
```

I am using xslt1.0 in BPEL 2.0 in SOA 11g.

Please help.

Comment: Why? They are two perfectly valid XML ways of expressing **exactly** the same information. You should not need a particular expression of it since both are valid XML.

Comment: Hi Quentin,  yes I know both are correct. But its the client requirement and they are unable to parse the above xml with their parser. I do not even have the access to see whats their issue.    :(

Comment: Oh. The client isn't using XML then. They are using something custom which is a lot like XML but different enough for lots of things to break horribly. You can't reliably use XML tools to generate the content for them. I'd recommend that they switch to using XML.